# Azure Active Directory and OWIN

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, owin, azure-active-directory

I'm attempting to add Azure Active Directory sign-in using OAuth2 to an existing MVC app.

I've got all of the OWIN boilerplate stuff in Startup.Auth.cs as well as the AccountController and Account/Views.

When attempting to access a controller with the Authorize attribute (Test/Test) I am shown the login page: http://mywebapp.com:12345/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FTest%2FTest)

When I click the button indicating that I want to log in to using Azure Active Directory I get sent to: http://mywebapp.com:12345/Account.aspx/ExternalLogin?ReturnUrl=%2FTest%2FTest

But that's all. The page is blank and I'm not prompted to log in anywhere.

Any guidance at all would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link in the Azure Management Portal for guidance around this feature is outdated. At the time of this writing the updated guidance is located at https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet. The crux of the problem was that MS expects you to use the OpenIDConnect Nuget Package to authenticate with Azure AD. The name of the package is: Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.